# COPYDATASTRUCT, WM_COPYDATA

Tags: c++, string, sendmessage, wm-copydata

I'm trying to send Data between two programs using `WM_COPYDATA` but i have a problem in the definition of `COPYDATASTRUCT`;

Here is the error:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include < stdlib.h >  
#include < vcclr.h >
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include "MyForm.h"


namespace TestGraphique {

using namespace System;
using namespace msclr::interop;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace std;
typedef struct tagCOPYDATASTRUCT {
    ULONG_PTR dwData;
    DWORD     cbData;
    PVOID     lpData;
} COPYDATASTRUCT;


/// <summary>
/// Description résumée de MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:


    typedef struct COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
     cpd.dwData = 0; // there is the problem
     cpd.cbData = dataToSend.GetLength(); // there is the problem 
    LPTSTR pszMem = new TCHAR[10000];
    HWND hWnd;
    HWND hWnd1;
    HWND hWnd2;
    HWND hWnd3;
    String^ a = "";
    String^ b = "";
    String^ c = "";
    String^ d = "";
    String^ result="";
    String^ TABLE = "";


    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message as text.  Just a picture with some red underlined text is not going to get you an answer.

Comment: Actually, search for that error text first. There's almost certainly an existing answer.

Comment: ther is the error sorry it's in frensh :
"<error-type>
un membre d'une classe managé ne peut pas être d'un type de classe non managé "
it's in the lines 
 COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;
cpd.dwData = 0;
cpd.cbData = dataToSend.GetLength();

Comment: _"<error-type> un membre d'une classe managé ne peut pas être d'un type de classe non managé "_: `a member of a managed class can not be of an unmanaged class type`

Comment: including ``<windows.h>`` should fix that problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

You are defining a type, not creating a variable. Change line `typedef struct COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;` to `COPYDATASTRUCT cpd;`.

You cannot execute code in the class definition. You should move these lines into a function:

```
cpd.dwData = 0;
cpd.cbData = dataToSend.GetLength();
```

You don't need to define `COPYDATASTRUCT` in your program. It is defined in windows.h. Remove this:

```
typedef struct tagCOPYDATASTRUCT {
    ULONG_PTR dwData;
    DWORD     cbData;
    PVOID     lpData;
} COPYDATASTRUCT;
```